# Installing Mavericks instead of Yosemite

Tags: macos

I am trying to install Mavericks (I have my reasons not to install Yosemite yet) on my MacBook with Lion. Obviously the possibility to upgrade to Mavericks from the App Store is now gone so one must install via installation dvd. I have downloaded one, mounted it, but when I try to start the installation, it fails with:

> To download and restore OS X, your computer eligibility will be verified with Apple.

When I press `Continue`:

> Could not find installation information for this machine.

Comment: Can you post the model please? Year etc.?

Comment: 15-inch, Early 2011, 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3, Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

Comment: From where did you download a Mavericks install DVD? You cannot have gotten it from Apple, so what you got is almost certainly a Trojan horse. It may install Mavericks. It will install more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one universal installation DVD for OS X. Each DVD has files specific to that Mac model. For example, you cannot use DVD from "early 2011" Mac for "late 2011" Mac. That OS X is called "Maverics" but each Mavericks build can start only Macs that were made before that build was released.

I found this accidentally while trying to restore my wife's Macbook with my own DVD (miner is older) and could not. On the other hand, her newer DVD worked with my Mac. So I made a research and found that not all OS X DVDs are equal.

Search for another DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue once. Try to disable WiFi on your Mac and connect through an iPhone or another Smartphone before the Verification-Process.

> Sometimes your Internet Connection isn't fast enough and fails because
>   of that.

1. Disable WiFi
2. Disconnect from LAN
3. Connect a Smartphone where you can tether OR go to a Internet Café